# Не отписывается и не прекращает работу обработчик события в C#, Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создал тестовую программу с графическим интерфейсом, чтобы понять как работают события, моя проблема в том, что через несколько изменеий текста через разные кнопки, обработчик `main_change` удаляет начальный текст, и не дает писать новый в элементе `TexBox` (тут `Tb`).

Сначала загружается текст в текстбокс-исчезает при вводе в него - потом кнопками можно менять тест, но через несколько изменений обработчик `main_change` съедает текст

Я планировал сделать чтобы при вводе текста текст который был исчезал. Как я не старался отключить `main_change`, неполучается.
Вот так вот.

Я новичок в этом, пробовал отписывать, пробовал ретурн, ничего не работает. Обработчик `S1` вызывается нажатием на кнопку.

Как остановить обработчик `main_change`, чтобы текст не исчезал через некоторое время изменений в текст-боксе через нажатия кнопок?

```
Тут код упрощен и подформатирован что-би он бил понятен:



        this.Load+= S;
        }
        
        //запускаеться кнопкой 1(button1 на скрине)
        public void S(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  t1=1;
            textbox.Text="Привіт";
            textbox.TextChanged+=main_change;
        }
        
        //после ввода удаляет текст и виводит в textbox последнюю букву
        public void main_change(object sender, EventArgs e){
        //условная конструкция не позволяет код

            if(t1==1){//условная конструкция останавливает удаление коде при его вводе, в теории
            t=textbox.Text;
            textbox.Text=t[t.Length-1].ToString();
            t1=0;}
            textbox.Select(textbox.Text.Length, 0);
        
            // пробую остановить обработчик
            textbox.TextChanged-=main_change;
        }
        
        void S1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            //запускаеться собитие нажатием кнопки 2(button1 на скрине)
            this.Back.Click+=S;
            
            textbox.Text="Тест";            
            
            ////тоже пробую остановить обработчик
            textbox.TextChanged-=main_change;           
        }









Исходний код:
int s1 = 0;
int s2 = 0;
int s3 = 0;
int s4 = 0;
string ss = " ";
string ss1 = " ";
string ss2 = " ";
int t1 = 0;
string t = " ";

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
        
    //добавляю сюда
    this.Load += S;
    //S(null,null);
}
    
public void S(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this.Load -= main_change;
    Tb.Text = "Привет";
    t1++;
    Tb.TextChanged += main_change;
    //main_change(null, null);
        
    l.Text = t1.ToString();
}

public void main_change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (t1 == 1)
    {
        t = Tb.Text;
        Tb.Text = t[t.Length - 1].ToString();
        t1 = 0;
    }
    Tb.Select(Tb.Text.Length, 0);
        
    l.Text = t1.ToString();
    return;
    //Tb.TextChanged -= main_change;
    //this.Back.Click += S;
    //Tb.TextChanged -= main_change;
}
    
void S1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Back.Click += S;
    //if(s2 == 0){
    Tb.Text = "Тест";
    l.Text = t1.ToString();
    this.Load += S;
    //s2 = 0;
        
    Tb.TextChanged -= main_change;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я создал тестовую программу с графическим интерфейсом, что-би понять как работают собития, моя проблема в том что через несколько изменеий теста через разние кнопки, обработчик "main_change" удаляет начальний текст, и не дает писать новий в елементе texbox(тут "Tb").